# Generating RegEx pattern for a given string

Tags: java, regex

I need to generate a RegEx pattern for a file name validation. But I am not used to RegEx pattern. I did try to generate patterns by using think [link](https://regexr.com/). I generated a pattern `(^.*$)|(^.*i.*$)` but it is not working as desired and got new pattern `^\d+(?:_[A-Za-z]+)?$` from an answer but some new conditions are required which I have listed below.

My required validations are as follows :

- 1234567890 => Valid
- 1234567890_Alphabet => Valid, '_' symbol is valid, other symbol as well as white space characters are invalid.
- 1234567890 - Alphabet => Invalid
- 1234567890alphabet => Invalid

New conditions :

- 11244422_134444_john => Valid
- 1234322_1234431 john => Invalid
- 1234222_134322-john => Invalid
- 12422344_12453222 => Valid

Some other validations :

- The string should start as numeric but not alphabet. i.e. Numeric only
- Underscore(_) preceded by numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by matching the digits, and optionally match an underscore and ASCII chars A-Za-z.

```
^\d+(?:_\d+)?(?:_[A-Za-z]+)?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?:_\d+)?` Optionally match `_` and 1+ digits
- `(?:_[A-Za-z]+)?` Optionally match `_` and 1+ times any of A-Za-z
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lJNYSc/1)

Comment: thank you for the answer but I have some new conditions that I have added in the description. Can u suggest some changes for new condition ? I tried to modify your regex pattern but couldn't succeed.

Comment: @SudeepShakya Did you change the question?

Comment: I added few new conditions. New conditions :

11244422_134444_john => Valid,
1234322_1234431 john => Invalid,
1234222_134322-john => Invalid,
12422344_12453222 => Valid

Comment: @SudeepShakya Like this? `^\d+(?:_\d+)?(?:_[A-Za-z]+)?$` https://regex101.com/r/lJNYSc/1

Comment: I will try and verify it .

Comment: please edit ^\d+(?:_[A-Za-z]+)?$  in your answer and I will accept it as the answer :) .

Answer (score 2):

```
[0-9]+($|_[A-Za-z]+)
```

see https://regex101.com/r/X5BMJ1/1 for live example

Basically, you get numbers first, and that's it ($) or you require _ followed by letters